# Plotting Chart Data for Training/Testing Data using Tensorflow/Plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-python

I have an issue  when my program takes the trained and tested data, plots it into a chart using plotly. The issue is the Chart Data is off-centered to the actual dates being pulled from yFinance and also the testing data causes a gap either above or below the training data depending on the current trend of the stock in question. Below you will find my code for drawing the chart and also a screenshot of the output from the program.

Code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

def draw(train_Y, test_Y, tickerName, data, train_pred, test_pred):
    
    # Create a new array that combines the actual train and test values
    combined_Y = np.concatenate([train_Y, test_Y])

    # Create the plot with two rows (one for price and one for RSI)
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.1)

    # Add price traces
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data.index[:train_Y.shape[0]], y=train_Y, mode='lines', name='Actual Train'), row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data.index[train_Y.shape[0]:], y=test_Y, mode='lines', name='Actual Test'), row=1, col=1)

    # Add RSI trace
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data.index, y=data['RSI'], mode='lines', name='RSI'), row=2, col=1)

    # Add Fibonacci levels as horizontal lines
    fibonacci_levels = [23.6, 38.2, 50, 61.8, 76.4]
    price_min = np.min(combined_Y)
    price_max = np.max(combined_Y)
    for level in fibonacci_levels:
        price_range = price_max - price_min
        price_offset = price_range * level / 100
        fig.add_shape(type='line', x0=data.index[0], x1=data.index[-1], y0=price_min + price_offset, y1=price_min + price_offset, line=dict(color='red', width=1, dash='dash'), row=1, col=1)

        # Add text annotations for the Fibonacci levels
        fig.add_annotation(x=data.index[0], y=price_min + price_offset, text=f"{level}%", showarrow=False, row=1, col=1)

    # Update the layout
    fig.update_layout(title=tickerName, showlegend=True, legend=dict(yanchor="top", y=0.99, xanchor="left", x=0.01))
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Adj Close', row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text='Date', row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='RSI', row=2, col=1)

    # Show the plot
    fig.show()
```

[TSLA Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2kB9.png)